# Why is $\mathrm{arctan}(0)$ not infinity?

Tags: trigonometry, reference-request, notation, definition

$\arctan x$ is defined as:

$$\arctan x = \frac{1}{\tan(x)} = \frac{1}{\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}}$$

if I now have $x = 0$ I should get:

$$\frac{1}{\frac{\sin(0)}{\cos(0)}} = \frac{1}{\frac{0}{1}} = \frac{1}{0} = \infty$$

but actually it is defined as $\mathrm{arctan}(0) = 0$.

What did I not get?

Bodo

Comment: $arctan \ne \frac{1}{\tan(x)}$

Comment: $\arctan x\ne {1\over\tan x}$  $\arctan x$ is the inverse function of $\tan x$. For example, $\arctan 1=\frac\pi 4$.

Comment: $\arctan \neq \cot$

Comment: I think you got confused with the inverse notation of $\arctan$. $\tan^{-1}\equiv\arctan\neq\cot$

Comment: Also:  even if it were $\cot (0)$ and ${1\over 0}$ **were** a thing (it's not) note that the right and left hand limits are opposites since $\cot x$ is an odd function, so even then $\infty$ wouldn't be right!

Comment: Ok I got it I am a math-autisimo :D - What can I mark as answer?

Comment: In the end - with Matthew's answer - this turned out to be a worthwhile question. So thanks, bodokaiser. And $\arctan(0)= 0$ for sure, because $\tan(0)=0$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've hit on the big notational ambiguity in the notation for trigonometric functions.  Usually $\tan^n(x)$ means $(\tan(x))^n$.  This includes negative powers:
$$
\tan^{-2}(x) = (\tan(x))^{-2} = \frac{1}{\tan(x)^2}
$$
etc.  **The exception is the exponent $-1$**.  We reserve $\tan^{-1}(x)$ to mean the inverse to the tangent function.  So $\tan^{-1}(0)$ is the angle whose tangent is zero, namely zero.

I try to avoid that ambiguity by never writing $\tan^{-1}$.  I'll use $\arctan$ for the inverse tangent and $\cot$ for $\frac{1}{\tan}$.  But the trap is so attractive it sometimes surpasses this measure.  I see students write things like:
$$
\color{red}{\arctan(x) = \tan^{-1}(x) = \frac{1}{\tan x} = \cot x}
\qquad\text{(Wrong!)}
$$
all the time.  The first and third equal signs are correct, but *not* the one in the middle.

I myself did this on a high school calculus exam 25 years ago.  Welcome to the club!

Comment: It should be mentioned, that depending on the country, they do in fact intend $\tan^{-1}(x)$ to be $\frac{1}{\tan(x)}$.  A problem which tends to confuse several international students in colleges across the world.  Most notably, I have seen Chinese and Korean students use $\tan^{-1}(x) = \frac{1}{\tan(x)}$, while here in America at least $\tan^{-1}(x)=\arctan (x)$.  For that reason especially, using $\arctan$ and $\cot$ will remove any possible ambiguity.

Comment: @JMoravitz: That is news to me, and distressing news indeed.  All the more reason to avoid this notation.

Comment: This is why that notation is horrendus and makes me sad.

Comment: In some contexts, doesn't $\tan^{-2}x = \arctan(\arctan(x))$?

Comment: But, of course, this question never mentions the notation $\tan^{-1}x$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews But it was *heavily* implied, else there was no reason to make the step $\arctan(x) = \frac{1}{\tan(x)}$ without an intermediary $\dots = \tan^{-1} = \dots$ in the middle.

Comment: Sure, but is also could have been confusion about the term "inverse function." It might well have been a $\tan^{-1}$ problem, just saying, you are supposing that, when it could have been other confusion.

Comment: @JohnJoy: You are correct, of course.  I am guessing that the OP is a student in calculus, and wouldn't be exposed to the usage of exponents for function iteration.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: This is why math teachers need to use Bayes' Theorem every day.  You know the probability of confusion given certain misconceptions is high, and you need to estimate the probability of certain misconceptions given their confusion.